# Can you simplify or paraphrase the highlighted part of the following text please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

When it says “most cursory reading of his life”

BY MISS HELEN KELLER

> The philosophy of Bahá'u'lláh deserves the best thought we can give it. I am returning the book so that other blind people who have more leisure than myself may be "shown a ray of Divinity" and their hearts be "bathed in an inundation of eternal love."
>
> I take this opportunity to thank you for your kind thought of me, **and for the inspiration which even the most cursory reading of Bahá'u'lláh's life cannot fail to impart**  . What nobler theme than the "good of the world and the happiness of the nations" can occupy our lives? The message of universal peace will surely prevail. It is useless to combine or conspire against an idea which has in it potency to create a new earth and a new heaven and to quicken human beings with a holy passion of service. (In a personal letter written to an American Bahá'í after having read something from the Braille edition of "Bahá'u'lláh and the New Era.")

- From Appreciations of the Bahá'í Faith page 15
  published in Bahá'í World, Vol. 8 (1938-1940), pages 595-628
  Wilmette, IL: Baha'i Publishing Committee, 194

Comment: It means exactly what it says. Cursory means **not detailed**. So if you were to read just a broad outline of somebody's life, with no detail, that would be "the most cursory reading of his life"

Answer (score 1):

Cursory is defined by the Online Oxford Dictionary [see here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cursory) as:

> Hasty and therefore not thorough or detailed.

The 'most cursory reading' of something would amount to a very brief scan that book or tract. So, Helen Keller is saying that the message contained in the philosophy of Bahá'u'lláh was so plain and clear that it could be  easily understood, without requiring in-depth study and analysis of the text.